# GLMM estimates holding some ranefs at mean value

Tags: mixed-model, lsmeans, glmmtmb

I'm trying to estimate annual expected counts (number of individuals of a species) by analyzing point count data from multiple sites across several years. The model looks like this:

```r
m <- glmmTMB(count ~ year_numeric + (1|year_factor) + (1|site),
             family = "poisson", data = data_i)
```

Here, I have a linear trend on year, as well as a random effect for year also, which efficiently captures non-linear fluctuations in abundance across years.

What I want are annual estimates of counts, with confidence intervals. Specifically, I want estimates of `count` for each year, taking into account uncertainty from the `year_numeric` (fixed) and `year_factor` (random) terms, while holding the `site` random effect at its mean value.

(I do *not* want population-level annual estimates and CIs that represent all of the uncertainty from the random `site` effect.)

I've tried `ggemmeans()`, but have not had much luck figuring out how I can tease what I want out of that function, although I seem to be circling it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

emmeans cannot do this. I suggest fitting a different model with site as a fixed effect. Then you can get EMMs averaged over site, and the between-site variance will be out of the way.

Comment: I will add that even with `site` in there as a random effect, the EMMs you see *do* average over the sites. Their contribution to the SE of the EMMs decreases via sigma_site / sqrt(#sites). If you don't want sigma_site taken into account and so you want to average over the particular sites in the dataset, then your inferences apply only to those particular sites and you are indeed regarding `site` as a fixed effect.